# How to mention time duration in days so that golang viper config can be loaded without errors?

Tags: go, viper-go

I have two configurations in the `.env` file as following

```
MAX_TOKEN_EXPIRY_DAYS=30d
ACCESS_TOKEN_DURATION=30m
```

The struct in golang to load the config looks like following

```golang
type AppConfig struct {
    MaxTokenExpiry      time.Duration `mapstructure:"MAX_TOKEN_EXPIRY_DAYS"`
    AccessTokenDuration time.Duration `mapstructure:"ACCESS_TOKEN_DURATION"`
}
```

Now the when I am trying to load the config, I am getting the following error

> `* error decoding 'MAX_TOKEN_EXPIRY_DAYS': time: unknown unit "d" in duration "30d"`

This may mean that I the issue was with `MAX_TOKEN_EXPIRY_DAYS=30d` line as it is not able to recognise the `d` tag. But the `m` tag in `ACCESS_TOKEN_DURATION=30m` runs well as `time.Duration` in golang is able to parse it well.

In the time package source code, I see the following constructs

```
Nanosecond  Duration = 1
Microsecond          = 1000 * Nanosecond
Millisecond          = 1000 * Microsecond
Second               = 1000 * Millisecond
Minute               = 60 * Second
Hour                 = 60 * Minute
```

**Is there any way to denote days in the config?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the [ParseDuration](https://pkg.go.dev/time#ParseDuration) called on your time string does not support `d` as a unit suffix

> Valid time units are "ns", "us" (or "µs"), "ms", "s", "m", "h".

You are better off using the hours equivalent of `30d` i.e. `720h` to resolve the ambiguity.

Also see issue/explanation in [golang/go](https://github.com/golang/go) for why the language designers decided to go with the choice. [Why doesn't time.ParseDuration() support days? #17767](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17767)

Comment: Wow..this thing seems completely new to me. I didn't know that 23 hours / day or 25 hours / day also exists. Thanks.